# NoClassDefFoundError: Adding Google Sign In to Android using AWS Amplify

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, google-authentication, google-authenticator

I am following the guide for adding google login to my android application: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication#google-login-in-your-mobile-app

And I am getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                  Process: com.xxxx.xxxx, PID: 16057
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazonaws/mobile/auth/userpools/CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider;
```

(note the error message is much longer)

My AuthenticatorActivity looks exactly like what they provide (with the imports needed). I am guessing it has something to do with the app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    // Mobile Client for initializing the SDK
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }

    // Google SignIn
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-google:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }

    // Sign in UI Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.8.+@aar') { transitive = true }

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But I am not sure what. Something with the way I am importing the mobile client? It is the way they say it should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the following to the dependency section of your app's build.gradle file :

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.8.+'
```

Hope it helps!